# Save Theano model doens't work for MLP net

Tags: pickle, theano, prediction

I'm trying to save a model obtained during training of a Multi layer Perceptron network built with Theano according to http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/mlp.py using the code shown in the Logistic regressor at http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py, in particular

```
# save the best model
with open('best_model.pkl', 'w') as f:
cPickle.dump(classifier, f)
```

but what I get is

> ... loading data ... building the model ... training epoch 1,
>   minibatch 74/74, validation error 38.333333 %
>        epoch 1, minibatch 74/74, test error of best model 41.666667 % Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mlp.py", line 423, in
>   
>       test_mlp()   File "mlp.py", line 406, in test_mlp
>       cPickle.dump(classifier, f, protocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute
>   lookup **builtin**.instancemethod failed

Since I met this problem also with the convolutional network, my question is: there is a general way to store a model in Theano, to be reused for prediction?

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments I'm using now

```
cPickle.dump((classifier.hiddenLayer.params,classifier.logRegressionLayer.params), f)
```

for saving and

```
classifier.hiddenLayer.W = cPickle.load(open('best_model_mlp.pkl'))[0][0]
```

for setting the weights (for instance) of the hiddenLayer in the classifier defined as

```
x = T.matrix('x')
classifier = MLP(
    rng=rng,
    input=x,
    n_in = 28*28,
    n_hidden= 500,
    n_out=10
)
```

but when I'm calling the very function

```
predict_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[classifier.input],
    outputs=classifier.logRegressionLayer.y_pred,
    )
```

I always have [0] as a prediction, even with a well trained net.
I'm still doing wrong in setting or saving parameters?

Answer (score 3):

I've been facing the same problem today. I don't know exactly the reason why this works with `'logistic_sgd.py`' and not with `'mlp.py'` but what you can do is to just store `'classifier.params'`

`'classifier.params'` are the only elements you need once you're done with the training. It should not be too hard to predict your classes from this parameters (this is already in your code).

Comment: I tried but I think I'm still having problems, as specified in the EDIT

Comment: My only suggestion is to use Lasagne python library for handling Theano, which allows saving and loading by simply calling 'get_params()' and 'set_params'.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and found this solution.
Even if only `'classifier.params'` should be necessary, `y_pred` and `input` also need to be initialized. Simple way is to store them via pickle and reload them.

Saving:

```
with open('best_model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    cPickle.dump((classifier.params, classifier.logRegressionLayer.y_pred, 
                 classifier.input), f)
```

Predicting function:

```
def predict(dataset, n_hidden, n_in, n_out):
    datasets = load_data(dataset)
    test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]
    test_set_x = test_set_x.get_value()
    test_set_y = test_set_y.eval()

    rng = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
    x = T.matrix('x')

    # Declare MLP classifier
    classifier = MLP(
        rng=rng,
        input=x,
        n_in=n_in,
        n_hidden=n_hidden,
        n_out=n_out
    )

    # load the saved model
    classifier.params, classifier.logRegressionLayer.y_pred,
        classifier.input = cPickle.load(open('best_model.pkl'))

    predict_model = theano.function(
        inputs=[classifier.input],*emphasized text*
        outputs=classifier.logRegressionLayer.y_pred)

    print("Expected values: ", test_set_y[:10])
    predicted_values = predict_model(test_set_x[:10])
    print("Predicted values:", predicted_values)
```

Hope this helps.